# how to compare wide characters "H2Oリテイリング" and "Ｈ2Ｏリテイリング"

Tags: c++, string, winapi, unicode

I am trying to compare some strings which are similar, for example:

1. The comparison of strings `"H2Oリテイリング"` and `"Ｈ2Ｏリテイリング"` should return true
2. The comparison of strings `"Ｈ２Ｏリテイリング"` and `"Ｈ2Ｏリテイリング"` should return true

I will get these strings by `TCHAR` array. Is there any way to compare these type of strings?

I tried by compare using character by character, but it doesn't work.

```
#define MAX_STRING 256
bool IsStringsEqual(TCHAR* str1, TCHAR* str2)
{
    if (_tcscmp(str1, str2) == 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;   
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    TCHAR original [MAX_STRING];
    ZeroMemory(original, sizeof(TCHAR) * MAX_STRING);
    _stprintf_s(original, TEXT("%s"), _T("Ｈ2Ｏリテイリング㈱"));

    TCHAR str1[MAX_STRING];
    ZeroMemory(str1, sizeof(TCHAR) * MAX_STRING);
    _stprintf_s(str1, TEXT("%s"), _T("H2Oリテイリング㈱"));
    if (IsStringsEqual(original,str1))
        wcout << endl << " Equal";

    TCHAR str2[MAX_STRING];
    ZeroMemory(str2, sizeof(TCHAR) * MAX_STRING);
    _stprintf_s(str2, TEXT("%s"), _T("Ｈ2Ｏリテイリング㈱"));
    if (IsStringsEqual(original, str2))
        wcout << endl << " Equal";

    TCHAR str3[MAX_STRING];
    ZeroMemory(str3, sizeof(TCHAR) * MAX_STRING);
    _stprintf_s(str3, TEXT("%s"), _T("Ｈ２Ｏリテイリング㈱"));
    if (IsStringsEqual(original, str3))
        wcout <<endl<< " Equal";

    return 0;
}
```

I'm expecting it to print Equal for all of the above comparisons.

Comment: When you **know**, that you are dealing with Unicode strings, stop [using generic-text mappings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/using-generic-text-mappings). Those haven't been useful in more than a decade now, and the only true reason to use them is to introduce (not so) subtle bugs.

Comment: nowadays you should never call the A version of API functions. Therefore `TCHAR` and `_T` are also useless

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like what you're looking for is the [Unicode Compatibility normalized forms](https://unicode.org/reports/tr15/). You can achieve it by using [`NormalizeString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Winnls/nf-winnls-normalizestring) prior to the comparison (the code doesn't handle errors, and strings that don't fit):

```
bool IsStringsEqual(wchar_t* str1, wchar_t* str2)
{
    wchar_t buf1[MAX_STRING], buf2[MAX_STRING];
    NormalizeString(NormalizationKD, str1, -1, buf1, MAX_STRING);
    NormalizeString(NormalizationKD, str2, -1, buf2, MAX_STRING);
    return wcscmp(buf1, buf2) == 0;
}
```

Comment: "*the code doesn't handle ... strings that don't fit*" - that is easy to solve using `std::wstring` or `std::vector<wchar_t>` instead of using `wchar[]` buffers.